# c# Label Visible and Invoke

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, invoke

I'm devolping a **Windows Mobile** aplication in **Compact Framework 2.0 SP1**.

How can I make invisible a label using invoke?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply want to change the Label's Visible property?  Generically speaking it's something like this:

```
private void SetVisibility(Control target, bool visible)
{
    if (target.InvokeRequired)
    {
        target.Invoke(new EventHandler(
            delegate
            {
                target.Visible = visible;
            }));
    }
    else
    {
        target.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```